# How to match strings even if only they match partially?

Tags: python, regex

I have two lists which I'd like to compare and if there is any match (even if partial) then carry out some action. I've set up this test code:

```
keywords = ['social media','social business','social networking','social marketing','online marketing','social selling',
    'social customer experience management','social cxm','social cem','social crm','google analytics','seo','sem',
    'digital marketing','social media manager','community manager']

metakeywords = ['top 10', 'social media blog', 'social media blog nomination']

if any(key in metakeywords for key in keywords):
    print 'Ok'
```

As you can see, there is a partial match between the 1st item of `keywords` and the 2nd and 3rd item of `metakeywords`, so it should print `Ok`. How can I do this?
Thanks!

Dani

Comment: What's the condition for a "partial match"?

Comment: what you mean _partial_ ? there is infinity partial matches

Comment: Does one string have to **contain** the other string?

Comment: I didn't explain well enough, sorry. In this example, I need any of the items in keywords to match (completelly or partially) with any of the items in metakeywords. So 'social media' has to be taken always as is and look for matches in metakeywords. In this case, it only partially matches some items in metakeywords, as metakeywords[1]='social media blog' (matches 'social media' but not 'blog') and the same happens for metakeywords[2].

Comment: You are going to get very different answers for this question. For instance, What's the difference between `social media` and just `social`? Should there be at least two words to consider it a match?

Comment: It looks to me like you want to know if any item in `metakeywords` completely contains any item in `keywords`. If so, please say that. Saying "match completely or partially" is not explaining what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to find out if any item in `keywords` is contained in any item in `metakeywords`, you can do this:

```
if any(key in metakey for key in keywords for metakey in metakeywords):
    print 'ok'
```